# zpool replace leaves pool degraded

Tags: freebsd, nas, zfs

been having issues with my FreeNAS 9.10 ZFS pool.

One of the drives was being warned as having many bad sectors so I decided to replace it. Had tremendous problems getting 'zpool replace' to recognise the new drive (it was in ada3, but it wouldn't accept that as parameter). Only thing I could figure out was to add the new drive as a 'spare' to the zpool and then use `zpool replace [poolname] [old device id] [spare device id]`

This worked and resilvered the new drive. However, once the resilver completed the pool remains in degraded state and seems to want the old drive back.

How do I convince it to 'forget' the old drive and accept the new one permanently??

many thanks

```
  pool: ZFS_NAS
state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be opened.  Sufficient replicas exist for
the pool to continue functioning in a degraded state.
action: Attach the missing device and online it using 'zpool online'.
  see: http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-2Q
scan: resilvered 989G in 4h42m with 0 errors on Mon May  2 19:45:33 2016
config:

NAME                                              STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
ZFS_NAS                                           DEGRADED     0     0     0
  raidz1-0                                        DEGRADED     0     0     0
    spare-0                                       DEGRADED     0     0     0
      12082773611957310038                        UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/gptid/1418d56c-431b-11e4-b9f7-28924a2f106f
      gptid/503d6d1c-106e-11e6-a169-28924a2f106f  ONLINE       0     0     0
    gptid/1608e28a-431b-11e4-b9f7-28924a2f106f    ONLINE       0     0     0
    gptid/1699dab6-431b-11e4-b9f7-28924a2f106f    ONLINE       0     0     0
spares
  16673430511205791764                            INUSE     was /dev/gptid/503d6d1c-106e-11e6-a169-28924a2f106f

errors: No known data errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the failed drive:

```
zpool detach ZFS_NAS gptid/1418d56c-431b-11e4-b9f7-28924a2f106f
```

or

```
zpool detach ZFS_NAS 12082773611957310038
```

Then the spare drive (gptid/503d6d1c-106e-11e6-a169-28924a2f106f) becomes a ONLINE member of ZFS_NAS pool.

Now you can add a new spare to the pool

[Refs.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gcvdi/index.html)